# How to add reference to DotNetNuke Library/Framework in a C# Project

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am developing a mobile app that uses DNN on the backend.  I want to create a Web API that receives a DNN UserID and returns the user's Profile Picture.

Most of the documentation and posts speak to developing Modules and focus on DNN Templates that are available.

All I want to do is add a reference to DNN Library in my Visual Studio Project so that I can access the DNN API.  I right click on references yet can't find DNN.

How is this accomplished?
Thanks.

EDIT... I'm developing on the same server that DNN is running on.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was a simple matter of pointing to the dll's I wanted to use in the bin subfolder of DotNetNuke.